# Finite presentation for left-exact endofunctors

Tags: ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

For a commutative unital ring  R  and a left-exact endofunctor  L  on the category of  R-modules, what is, or should be, the definition of finite presentation for  L ?  Possibilities:

L( R )  is finitely presented over  R .

For every  R-algebra  S ,  L( S )  is finitely presented over  S .

For some category  C  (but which one?) having  L  as an object, closed under filtered colimits, the structural mapping  colim Hom( L , M_a ) -> Hom( L , colim M_a )  is bijective for every filtered diagram  { M_a }  of  C-objects.